# gcc problem -> stdio.h not found

Tags: compiling, gcc, libraries, compiler

I have to compile one programme. theoretically i need just to change the two path...

can you help me?

Makefile

```
# Original
#CC=arm-1136jf_s_r1_vfp_hard_float-linux-gnueabi-gcc
#CFLAGS= -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections --sysroot=/home/mguivarch/Desktop/buildroot-2011.08-advansee/build/staging/ 
#LDFLAGS= -Wl,--gc-sections -lpthread -lrt -lm -L/home/mguivarch/Desktop/buildroot-2011.08-advansee/build/staging/usr/lib

# Change I made
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS= -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections --sysroot=/home/mihai/Desktop/MIPSEE/Programme
LDFLAGS= -Wl,--gc-sections -lpthread -lrt -lm -L/usr/include


EXEC=livic_sync

all: $(EXEC)


livic_sync: capture.o main.o clientTCP.o
$(CC) -o livic_sync capture.o main.o clientTCP.o $(LDFLAGS)


clientTCP.o: ClientTCP.c main.h
$(CC) -o clientTCP.o -c ClientTCP.c $(CFLAGS)

capture.o: capture.c ClientTCP.h
$(CC) -o capture.o -c capture.c $(CFLAGS)


main.o: main.c capture.h
$(CC) -o main.o -c main.c $(CFLAGS)


clean:
rm *.o


mrproper: clean
rm $(EXEC)
```

vPro:~/Desktop/MIPSEE/Programme$ make

gcc -o capture.o -c capture.c -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections --sysroot=/home
/mihai/Desktop/MIPSEE/Programme

capture.c:9:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

make: *** [capture.o] Error 1

---

:~/Desktop/MIPSEE/Programme$ ls -l

total 216

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai 15905 Oct 30 19:34 capture.c

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai   453 Jul 17  2012 capture.h

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai  3228 Jul 18  2012 ClientTCP.c

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai   217 Sep 13  2012 ClientTCP.h

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai   948 Feb 10  2012 ClientUDP.c

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai   141 Feb  9  2012 ClientUDP.h

drwxrwxr-x 18 mihai mihai  4096 Nov  1 10:11 html

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai  6459 Oct 30 19:31 main.c

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai  1374 Jun 21  2012 main.h

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai   865 Nov  1 12:46 Makefile

-rw-r--r--  1 mihai mihai   870 Nov  1 12:30 Makefile~

-rw-rw-r--  1 mihai mihai 75566 Nov  1 10:11 mihaiDoxygenConfig

-rw-rw-r--  1 mihai mihai 75568 Oct 30 14:57 mihaiDoxygenConfig~

drwxr-xr-x  3 mihai mihai  4096 Oct 30 19:55 MIPSEE

:~/Desktop/MIPSEE/Programme$

---

:~/Desktop/MIPSEE/Programme$ locate stdio.h

/usr/include/stdio.h

/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/stdio.hpp

/usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/stdio.h

/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstdio.h

/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h

/usr/include/unicode/ustdio.h

/usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/CORE/nostdio.h

/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h

Comment: Usage of the `--sysroot=dir` option tells the compiler to look in `dir/usr/include` for the standard header files instead of the standard system location `/usr/include` - this is typically used in cross-compilation scenarios - is that what you are trying to do? if so you will likely need the appropriate SDK (target system header files and libraries) for the MIPSEE target installed into your `~/Desktop/MIPSEE/Programme/` directory.